# How to define different context menus for different objects in autodesk forge

Tags: viewer, autodesk-forge, forge

I want to define different context menus for different objects in forge viewer,this is my code

```
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT,function(e){
     if(viewer.getSelection().length==0){return;}
     var selectId=viewer.getSelection()[0];
     viewer.search("Cabinet",function(ids){
          if(ids.indexOf(selectId)!=-1){
               viewer.registerContextMenuCallback('CabinetMsg', function (menu, status) {
                   if (status.hasSelected) {
                        menu.push({
                            title: "CabinetMsg",
                            target: function () {
                                openLayer('CabinetMsg','954','775','CabinetMsg.html')
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
          }else{
                viewer.registerContextMenuCallback('CabinetMsg', function (menu, status) {
                    if (status.hasSelected) {
                        menu.forEach(function(el,index){
                            if(el.title=="CabinetMsg"){
                                menu.splice(menu.indexOf(index),1)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                });
            }

        })
    });
```

But push elements to the array  is always later than the context menus show. My custom context menu is always show when I select another object.  What I can do?

Answer (score 1):

The codes you provided will create 2 new sub items to the context menu. Here is a way for this case, i.e. you have to write your own `ViewerObjectContextMenu`. In addition, you need do `hitTest` in `ViewerObjectContextMenu.buildMenu` to get dbId selected by the mouse right clicking. Here is the example for you:

```
class MyContextMenu extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.ViewerObjectContextMenu {
  constructor( viewer ) {
    super( viewer );
  }

  isCabinet( dbId ) {
    // Your logic for determining if selected element is cabinet or not.
    return false;
  }

  buildMenu( event, status ) {
    const menu = super.buildMenu( event, status );

    const viewport = this.viewer.container.getBoundingClientRect();
    const canvasX = event.clientX - viewport.left;
    const canvasY = event.clientY - viewport.top;

    const result = that.viewer.impl.hitTest(canvasX, canvasY, false);

    if( !result || !result.dbId ) return menu;

    if( status.hasSelected && this.isCabinet( result.dbId ) ) {
      menu.push({
          title: 'CabinetMsg',
          target: function () {
              openLayer( 'CabinetMsg', '954', '775', 'CabinetMsg.html' );
          }
      });
    }

    return menu;
   }
}
```

After this, you could write an extension to replace default viewer context menu with your own menu. Here also is the example:

```
class MyContextMenuExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
    constructor( viewer, options ) {
        super( viewer, options );
    }

    load() {
        this.viewer.setContextMenu( new MyContextMenu( this.viewer ) );
        return true;
    }

    unload() {
        this.viewer.setContextMenu( new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.ViewerObjectContextMenu( this.viewer ) );
        return true;
    }
}
```

Hope this help.